# How to force click function to run once

Tags: jquery

I have this function, but I only want the entire function to run one time.  How?

```
$("a.en").not("a.flag").click(function() {
   $("iframe.goog-te-banner-frame").attr("style","visibility:hidden");
   $("body").attr("style","top:0px !important");
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/):

```
$("a.en").not("a.flag").one('click', function() {
   $("iframe.goog-te-banner-frame").attr("style","visibility:hidden");
   $("body").attr("style","top:0px !important");
});
```

That will only execute the handler once (per matched element).

If you only want it to execute once, regardless of how many elements are matched by `$("a.en").not("a.flag")`, you could do this:

```
$("a.en").not("a.flag").on('click', function runOnce() {
   $("iframe.goog-te-banner-frame").attr("style","visibility:hidden");
   $("body").attr("style","top:0px !important");
   $("a.en").not("a.flag").off('click', runOnce);
});
```

Comment: Thanks I will accept this answer when I can ASAP.  Can I ask you one more question while here?  If not, I will post another questions instead.

Comment: If the question helps clarify something in my answer, or if my answer doesn't completely answer your original question. Otherwise, it'd probably be better to ask a new question.

Comment: Your answer is correct.  But I just realized that it's the "onclick" attribute causing the problem, not the "click" event using jQuery.  Can you just guide me on how I can do the same targeting the attribute instead.  No need to post more code above, if you can post in this comment area.

Comment: So I don't want to remove "onclick" attribute, just disable the attribute after it runs one time.

Comment: I'm not sure how you'd do it with inline event handlers. You might just need to use a bool flag, something like this: `var hasRun = false; function clickHandler() { if (hasRun) { return; } hasRun=true; /*...*/ }`